# How can I prevent Selenium from trying to download chromedriver?

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

Selenium (Windows, Chrome, Python) is trying to verify and download the new chromedriver version, but the download links are offline for some reason. But I already have the current version (118) and the testing is crashing due to timeout.

I'm using

> service = webdriver.ChromeService(executable_path=directory)

being directory the folder where chromedriver is located.

How can I prevent Selenium from trying to download?